# To shard or not to shard?  GAE/java/jdo

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sharding, bigtable

I'm currently porting some work from MySQL to Google App Engine/Java.  I'm using JDO, as well as the lower level java API where required.

I read through the optimization guide about sharding counters: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html

I'm still building the foundation of my app.  I know that premature optimization is the root of all evil; but this is clearly documented in order to avoid contention.  So I'm having trouble deciding if I should be biased one way or the other.

So should I be sharding counters (and other possibly higher frequency write operation objects) by default, or should I go forward without sharding and implement on an as needed basis?

Comment: What are you going to do with those counters? I hope you'll not use them for something like auto increment ids for your entities.

Comment: Thanks for the concern, but no need to worry.  I'm going to be counting things like page views and user actions.

Comment: Sounds good. Maybe use memcache and purge into db every 5 mins with cron?

Comment: Do you really need to count pageviews yourself, direct to the datastore? That's a recipe for scalability issues in any system, and the sort of thing tools like analytics were built for.

Comment: The exact situation I'm more worried about right now has to do with voting.  I'm not so much worried about the speed of updating as I am about avoiding datastore contention.  I'm afraid that if I had an artifact being updated due to having a lot of votes cast simultaneously that contention would cause vote(s) to be dropped.  I realize that this might be overkill, but I don't have the benefit of hindsight here - so I'm taking a "better safe than sorry approach".

Comment: For pageviews, I probably will end up taking the memcache road as @chrouvim suggested (I realize I don't need %100 accuracy in that regard).  Also worth noting; this isn't for professional use...well at least not yet ;)  I'm really just trying to learn a lot and I'm biasing implementation decisions towards something that might be more complicated than I actually need for the sake of learning about it.  Kind of getting restless/bored with work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The salient meaning of "premature" here is "before the proper time." Designing to avoid limits, when those limits are well understood, is not premature.

Shard your counters.

Answer (score 3):

Even with effective sharding, maintaining aggregates can add some substantial load to your application.  If you *need* that aggregate, and you can't afford an approximation; then using a sharded aggregate is *not* a premature optimization; there is no next best alternative.  If you don't actually need the counter, then the time it will take to implement it could be better spent elsewhere.